# ValueObject json deserialization returns Null

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, value-objects

I am trying to implement valueobject in asp.net core with ef core. I have money as value object and product which has money as price property. The problem is that money is serialized in product table but deserialization returns null. I tried debug mode but it even doesn't go in money class for deserialization.
Note:I used [NotMapped] because migration gave me error that money needs primary key, But I didn't need table for money and I wanted money to be serialized as a price field in product table.
my money model:

```
[NotMapped]
public class Money
{
    public static readonly Money Empty = new Money(0);
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }

    protected Money()
    {
    }

    public Money(decimal value) : this()
    {
        if (value < 1)
            throw new Exception("value is invalid");
        Value = value;
    }
  }
```

my product model:

```
public class Product
 {
    public Product()
    {

    }
    public Product(string name, decimal price)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new Exception("Name is invalid");
        Name = name;
        Price = new Money(price);
    }
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Money Price { get; private set; }
  }
```

my dbcontext:

```
public class StoreDbContext:DbContext
  {
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=XXX;initial catalog=Basket2;integrated security=true");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductConfiguration());
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        //    .HasKey(lc => new { lc.Id });
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderLine> OrderLines{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products{ get; set; }
  }
```

my productconfiguration:

```
   public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
    {

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {

      var test=  builder.Property(c => c.Price).
            HasConversion(c => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c), c => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Money>(c));


     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SerializeObject and DeserializeObject cannot always underestand a code successfully, that's why we have ISerializable interface. I believe, if you implement it, your issue would be fixed. Please have a look on the links below:

[Implementing ISerializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=netframework-4.8)

[Newtonsoft and ISerializable](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm)